# office 365 api integration in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, outlook, office365

I am trying to add connected service to visual studio to integrate office 365 api, but i can't  add, is it possible to integrate office 365 api in visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add Office 365 as a connected service, you need to have Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4 and Office 365 API Tools version 1.4.50428.2.